# Вывод форматированного текста в окно (C++, WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, text

В установщике пакета ПО нужно вывести длинный текст. Текст надо растянуть по ширине, разместить по центру заголовок "ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКОЕ СОГЛАШЕНИЕ", где-то выделить жирным, где-то наклонным, сделать отступы и навести прочую красоту.

**Как это правильно сделать из кода?** Или проще нарисовать в графическом редакторе, сохранить картину, и подгрузить её фоном (только её придётся как-то скролить - как?)?

PS: желательно конечно из кода, чтобы можно было подтянуть файл и текст встал на своё место.

Comment: Используйте [msdn richedit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) он поддерживает форматированый текст.

Comment: Как вариант сложнее, OLE-window можно отобразить Web-страницу с форматированием.

Comment: Для richedit текст можно набросать в ворде или wordpad-е (сохранить RTF), как грузить [вот](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) пример.

Comment: А обязательно использовать FILE чтобы загнать текст в richedit? Если файл будет дописан в конец установщика и он просто прочитает себя при запуске, получится залить этот контент в richedit? Просто установщик формируется на сервере, и при запросе на скачивание клиент получает один единственный файл установщика.

Comment: нет, можно написать в stream "свою" загрузку с памяти. С памяти текст грузится замечательно.

Comment: Для stream достаточно richedit.h или там ещё что-то подключать надо? (работаю с MinGW - какой-то дополнительный параметр линковщику нужен?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот наброски того, как можно форматированый текст вывести в rtf + richedit под windows.

```
// Функция взять-отдать текст
int GetSetRtf(HWND Handle, char* data, int max){
DWORD st[5]; // можно использовать стандартную структуру это что б не искать библиотеки
st[0] = (DWORD)&st[3];
st[1] = 0 ;
st[2] = (DWORD)&EditStreamCallback;
st[3] = (DWORD)data;
st[4] = max;

if (max ==  0 ) {
   return ::SendMessageA(Handle,WM_USER + 73,2,(DWORD)&st); // EM_STREAMIN
   } else {
   ::SendMessageA(Handle,WM_USER + 74,2,(DWORD)&st);
   }

}

// Вспомагательный стрим
DWORD __stdcall EditStreamCallback(char ** cookie,LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG FAR * pcb){
int x = (int)cookie[1];
int j = 0;
if (x == 0 ) {
   while (*cookie[0] != 0 ) {
     pbBuff[x++] = *cookie[0]++;
     if (x>=cb) break;
   }
   if (x<cb)  pbBuff[x] = 0;
   *pcb = x;
  }
return 0;
}

// Как использовать
CoInitialize(0); // Надо
InitCommonControls(); // в msdn написано что надо в случае использования стилей окна, без работает
LoadLibraryA("riched20.dll"); // Тоже надо, новая библиотека называется Msftedit.dll можно её

HWND Edit1 =  CreateWindow("RichEdit20A","(info)",
   WS_VISIBLE  | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN  |ES_LEFT,
  151,32,600,200,w.Handle/*родительское окно*/,0,hInstance,0);

GetSetRtf(Edit1, "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1251\\deff0\\deflang1049{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\\f0 62452}" , 0);
```

Ссылка на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Если вы хотите использовать картинки в rtf то вам нужно ещё в инициализацию подключить ещё один модуль. В большинстве случаев этих набросков хватит. Сделать текст не редактируемым и т д - установить стили ES_***.

Ещё нужно заметить что 20 - не самая последняя версия - но везде 98 XP 2008 рабоает. Для юникода нужна W-версия вместо А. Есть где-то описание какая версия что умеет. Думаю поддержку старых версий отключат не скоро. Уж очень много программ используют richedit.

Линковщику говорить ничего не нужно - т.к. доп-функции не используются.  `#include <richedit.h>` не всегда хорошо работает, нужно или подправлять define, или `#include <richedit20.h>` подключать. Вторая версия (20) имеет достаточно хороший функционал, а компилятор его не всегда "подключает".

Пару слов по тегам. `\` нужно экранировать `\\` двумя (но в char* их четыре). `\pard;`-новая сторка (\r\n rtf игнорирует) `\b` `\b0` поставить/убрать жирный. Ссылку на хороший хелп не подскажу, но найти не сложно.

Comment: riched20.dll - MinGW не знает -lriched20. Не подскажете что можно передать его линковщику?

Comment: Его не нужно линковать. Его нужно **загрузить**, используя [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) в коде напрямую (в секции WinMain или FormCreate и т п) **обязательно**. Пример который я написал - можно даже не подключать richedit.h. Констаты есть в commctrl.h. Я ж пример кода написал.

Comment: Наверное правильнее сказать динамическая. Статическая прилинковуется к exe-шнику напрямую. Вот ещё вам пример с msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Я вам  InitCommonControls не написал.

Comment: Спасибо! Текст вывел. Но надо статически линковаль... блин ((

Comment: Что значит статическая линковка? Что вам мешает просто перед CreateWindow поставить LoadLibrary? Вам никто не запрещает через линкер подключить - но это больше писанины - нужно сделать implib, потом lib прописать через прагму или параметры. Сделать на линк на любую функцию (определится какую) - работать будет, но проще первый вариант. Почитайте про типы связывания... может...

Comment: Приложение должно запускаться на чистой только установленной системе и не требовать никаких библиотек, всё должно быть в exe-шнике - требование руководства ((

Comment: эта библиотека идёт в комплекте с любой голой виндой 98/xp/2003/2008. Она является стандартной для винды, на её базе построен интерфейс винды. В папке system32 она всегда есть на равне с kernel32.dll и другими, даже если не установлено офис. Проблем с ней не будет.

Comment: Ну понятно. В любом случае, если LoadLibrary вернёт NULL (чего по-идее быть не должно), можно выгрузить её из установщика в файл в папке запуска установщика перед созданием окна. Думаю сработает. Ещё раз СПАСИБО!